# Ruby efficiently determining the largest (longest) of 2 arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to efficiently find the largest given two pre-existing arrays.  I found many threads on finding the largest *value*, yet I have not found any specifically about the longest.

This is as a programming exercise to build a mergesort.

tl;dr: Efficiently determine which is larger and assign largest to base_array and smaller to injection_array.

#### METHOD 1 - works, feels overly verbose/inelegant

```
if unsortedB.length > unsortedA.length
  base_array, injection_array = unsortedB, unsortedA
else
  base_array, injection_array = unsortedA, unsortedB
end
```

#### METHOD 2 - pseudocode, currently returns largest FIRST ELEMENT

```
base_array = [unsortedB,unsortedA].max
injection_array = [unsortedB,unsortedA].min
```

**EDIT:** updated for clarity: want both assignments, not just largest

Comment: Verbosity/inelegance ≠ inefficiency. What are you really looking for?

Comment: Your description implies that you are only interested in base_array, yet your code examples show that you want a base_array and injection_array.  Could you clarify this, please?

Comment: @vol7ron not homework, just practicing sorting algos and inappropriately using ruby).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall True, I guess the best balance between the two as efficient as I can make it while being quite readable and not relying on ruby-specific helper methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done fairly elegantly in one line:

```
injection_array, base_array = [unsortedA, unsortedB].sort_by(&:length)
```

Though whether this is any more readable than the alternatives remains open to discussion.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to `max` and `min`, ruby has `max_by` and `min_by` that allow you to specify how elements are to be compared.

For the common case where you want both maximum and minimum there `minmax_by`, for example

```
short, long = [unsortedA,unsortedB].minmax_by(&:length)
```

However, I don't think there's much wrong with the plain old if statement, and I suspect it will end up being faster.

Comment: Cool, actually never seen `minmax_by` before.

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator makes this a one-liner:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2,3,4,5]

base_array, injection_array = a.length > b.length ? [a,b] : [b,a]

p base_array
p injection_array
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I started out on that path but that only sets 1 of my target variables `base_array = b` but `injection_array != a`

Comment: Updated the answer to include injection_array.